# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Message' in NEXT.JS (typescript)

Tags: javascript, next.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a clone of messenger using Next.Js as practice and while using typedefinitions and using "upstash, Serverless access to Redis database". I followed the entire procedure through documentation given by both NEXT.Js and Upstash Console using Node.js(already given on console of upstash).
My typeDefinitions for a Message is as following: (typings.d.ts)

```
export type Message = {
    id: string,
    message: string,
    created_at: number,
    username: string,
    profilePic: string,
    email: string,
  };
```

Now in order to "addMessages" i have used api handling procedure (async promise) and created the following:

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import redis from '../../redis';
import { Message }  from '../../typings';

type Data = {
    message: Message;
}

type ErrorData = {
    body: string
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data | ErrorData>
) {
    if(req.method != 'POST') {
        res.status(405).json({ body: "Method Not Allowed"
    });
    return;
    }

    const  { message }  = req.body;

    const newMessage = {
        ...message,
        //Replace the timestamp of the user to the timestamp of the server
        created_at: Date.now(),
    };
    // Push to upstash redis db

    await redis.hset("messages", message.id, JSON.stringify(newMessage));

  res.status(200).json({ message: "newMessage" })
}
```

on "type Data={
message: Message;}"
and on last line of the code
"
res.status(200).json({ message: "newMessage" })"

as soon as i hit save it gives the following error :
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Message'.
I have tried hard reload, but the error remains there. Following this error as i hit a random message on Frontend, the console gave the following error:
'"A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"'
I have already checked the console of upstash please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your `Data` interface requires an object with `message` as key and `Message` interface as value. Instead you are trying to send a string `newMessage`.

So you can do 3 things:

1. I see you have a `newMessage` object, so instead of sending the string `"newMessage"`, send the `newMessage` object, like so:

```
res.status(200).json({ message: newMessage });
```

2. set the type of `Data` as

```
type Data=Message
```

This way you can send the message as

```
res.status(200).json({ message: "newMessage" });
```

3. send the message in a nested key value pair

```
res.status(200).json({ message: {message: "newMessage" });
```

I would recommend the first one or the second one.

Also, typescript might complain that other fields from the `Message` interface are missing if you choose to send just a string. I would recommend that you make them optional.

Comment: thank you so much for writing the answer in breif explanation. It solved my entire issue in wink of an eye. Will always be grateful. God bless. I after reading your answer realized the mistake i was making. your first line helped me the most. once again thank you. I owe you. <3